# Event handling of vuejs, fabricjs and window

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fabricjs

On our project we are using Vuejs and Fabricjs, to draw something to canvas and edit it etc.

Recently we started refactoring and we decided that it would be nice, if we would unite all events under one event bus. Because now we had 3 types of events: vuejs events, fabricjs canvas events, window events.

So we have created simple EventBus class like so:

```
import EventEmitter from 'events'

class EventBus extends EventEmitter {}

const eb = new EventBus()
export default eb
```

We can then import this event bus anywhere like `import eventBus from '@/EventBus'`

So by using this event bus, our classes that are not vue components can react to these events and these events can be emitted or catched in vue components too.

Now we would like to transfer also the fabricjs events to our event bus, which would remove the need for the classes (and vue components) to have direct reference to canvas to register to its events.

So lets say we would have one class where we have reference to canvas and we would transfer the events to our event bus like so:

```
this._canvas.on({
      'mouse:down': e => eventBus.emit('canvas:mouse:down', e),
      'mouse:up': e => eventBus.emit('canvas:mouse:up', e)
})
```

While this works, I noticed it has some performance overhead on events like `mouse:moving` while operating with many objects on canvas, where the events are called fast.

**My question is**, should we even be doing this like that? Or provide all classes access to canvas, so that they can all register directly to its event bus and remove this 'unnecessary' transfer from one event bus to another?

My colleagues would also like to move window events to our event bus, but that seems even more wrong to me since everything we have has access to the window object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the particular case of the fabricjs canvas, that kind of operation should not be that much expensive.

The fabricjs event on mouse move does some standard operations that are lightly dependant from the quantity of objects you have.

Those operations are:
extraction of mouse position and a couple of addition, multiplication to get canvas relative coordinates. Loop trough objects and see if an object intersect that coordinates. Bind the event handler to the canvas instance and call it.

your event forwarding should cost nothing.

To the point if it makes sense or not, that depends on the project. If the benefits of clear code and organization outweight an extra function wrapping, then it makes sense.

For example, importing your canvas instance everywhere to make it accessible, will bind your event handlers to that particular canvas, your code will start to reference that in an hard way that the day you want to add another canvas to your project you possibly be in trouble.

Comment: we indeed did it for canvas and vue in the end, co we are not using vuejs event bus, but a general one that we can use everywhere. Window events we left intact, since we have access to the window object everywhere. The point with possible problem with "hard" binding directly to canvas is also valid.